# 'denigrare' & 'sbianchettare': possibili parole razziste

Tags: grammar

C'era una recente domanda posta su English Language & Usage con la quale era chiesto se la parola '*denigrate*' dovesse essere evitata in quanto, derivando da 'negro', sarebbe razzista.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209021/is-denigrate-a-racist-word

A giudizio dei rispondenti lì pare che questo problema non si ponga.

Allora mi chiedo, è così anche nella lingua italiana per 'denigrare'?

Se sì, potremmo anche porci analoghi problemi sull'uso della parola 'sbianchettare'?

Comment: Se anche fosse, non vedo il motivo per cui evitare queste parole. *Denigrare* e *sbianchettare* sono parole che non hanno assolutamente alcun significato razzista, qualsiasi sia la loro etimologia.

Comment: Inoltre, a orecchio direi che *denigrare* viene dal latino *nigro*, che indica il colore nero, e non dal più moderno *negro* per offendere le persone di pelle scura.

Comment: “Negro” non è un termine “per offendere le persone di pelle scura”: è una parola italiana che fino all'altro ieri significava “nero” in generale («sei nella terra negra...») e fino a ieri, se non a stamattina, significava “nero” riferito alle persone, usato tra l'altro da Primo Levi, Elsa Morante e molti altri che sicuramente non avevano intenti razzisti.

Answer (score 12):

Secondo il Garzanti deriva dal latino, e significherebbe "oscurare" "annerire"
http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=denigrare

Sempre secondo il Garzanti "sbianchettare" deriva da "bianchetto" (il liquido per cancellare) con il prefisso "s-".

In entrambe le etimologie non c'è nulla che possa associarle a significati razzisti.

Al momento nell'uso comune credo di non di averle mai sentite utilizzare con accezioni razziste.